# Printing URL links within a function

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a movie database. I need View, Edit, and Delete to link to other pages within my site.  For example, I want view to go to a link called show.php but I need the page to dynamically load with the $movie[id] information. How can I do that from within the function. Here's what I have so far:

```
  printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",
      $movie['id'],
      $movie['title'],
      $movie['director'],
      $movie['year'],
      printDropdown ($movie['cast']),
      '<img src="'.$movie ['poster'].'" height="100" width="75"/>',
      '<a class="action" href="">'.'View'.'</a>',
      '<a class="action" href="">'.'Edit'.'</a>',
      '<a class="action" href="">'.'Delete'.'</a>',
 );
}
```

Edited on 5/12:
I decided to take a different approach. The poster column appears in the table but it shows that all the images are broken even though the URL image source is correct for each array. What am I missing from the table column that contains the image source?

```
<?php foreach($movies as $movie) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo h($movie['id']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($movie['title']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($movie['director']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($movie['year']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo printDropdown($movie['cast']); ?></td>
    <td><img src="'.$movie['poster'].'" height="100" width="75"/></td>
    <td><a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('show.php?id=' . h(u($movie['id']))); ?>">View</a></td>
    <td><a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('edit_movie.php?id=' . h(u($movie['id']))); ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a class="action" href="">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on PHP GET. And you should be able to do it.

You have to do something like this:

```
 printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",
      $movie['id'],
      $movie['title'],
      $movie['director'],
      $movie['year'],
      printDropdown ($movie['cast']),
      '<img src="'.$movie ['poster'].'" height="100" width="75"/>',
      '<a class="action" href="show.php?action=view&id=' . $movie['id'] . '">'.'View'.'</a>',
      '<a class="action" href="">'.'Edit'.'</a>',
      '<a class="action" href="">'.'Delete'.'</a>',
 );
```

Within the other page. like show.php you can get the given action and id like:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // the given id
$action = $_GET['action']; // view
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GET method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

In this case you place parameters in the url of the href attributes. Like:

```
<a href='<url>?movie_id={$movie['id']}&title={$movie['title']}'>
```